# Xamarin Relative Layout Constraint Class RelativeToParent unexpected output?

Tags: c#, xamarin, label, constraints, android-relativelayout

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App1
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {

        public MainPage()
        {
            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout();

            Label upperLeft = new Label
            {
                Text = "Upper Left",
                FontSize = 20
            };
            relativeLayout.Children.Add( upperLeft ,
                Constraint.Constant(0), Constraint.Constant(0)
                );
            Label constantLabel = new Label
            {
                Text = "Constants are Absolute",
                FontSize = 20
            };
            relativeLayout.Children.Add(constantLabel,
                Constraint.Constant(100),
                Constraint.Constant(100),
                Constraint.Constant(50),
                Constraint.Constant(200)
                );
            Label halfWayDown = new Label
            {
                Text = "Halfway down and across",
                FontSize = 20
            };
            relativeLayout.Children.Add(halfWayDown,
                  Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
                  {
                      return parent.Width / 2;
                  }),
                  Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
                  {
                      return parent.Height / 2;
                  })
                  ) ;
            this.Content = relativeLayout;
        }

        
    }
}
```

I have 3 labels one placed at upper left corner , second one on some random `location(100,100)` ,  third one at half of parent width and height. I am having an issue with the last label. I don't know why the text of the last label is crossing the screen and why it is not changing the line. Also when I pass the value for `width` and `height` of the last label the text of the label changes the line, why does that happen? This behaviour (text crosses the screen) occurs when I pass only two arguments to the third label. I have also tried with the first the label where , when I pass only two arguments to the `Add-method` the text changes its line automatically. Can anyone tell me how the method `RelativeToParent` works? Also what is default `width` and `height` value if i did not pass them? Why does the text in the last label not change the line?
[Link for the image of the output i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI6iZ.jpg)

Comment: I can't answer your entire question but, `RelativeToParent` has documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.constraint.relativetoparent?view=xamarin-forms) which you can read more about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't set the width of Label `halfWayDown`,so the text is displayed on one line by default, with the following portion of the text truncated.

You can set the width of Label `halfWayDown` when adding it to `Children`:

```
        relativeLayout.Children.Add(halfWayDown,
              Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
              {
                  return parent.Width / 2;
              }),
              Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
              {
                  return parent.Height / 2;
              }),

               // set the 1/3 width  of parent
               Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
               {
                 return parent.Width * 0.5;
               })
              );
```

You can also set the `MaxLines` ,`LineBreakMode` for your Label.

Please refer to the following code:

```
    public MainPage()
    {

        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout();

        Label upperLeft = new Label
        {
            Text = "Upper Left",
            FontSize = 20
        };
        relativeLayout.Children.Add(upperLeft,
            Constraint.Constant(0), Constraint.Constant(0)
            );
        Label constantLabel = new Label
        {
            Text = "Constants are Absolute",
            FontSize = 20
        };
        relativeLayout.Children.Add(constantLabel,
            Constraint.Constant(100),
            Constraint.Constant(100),
            Constraint.Constant(50),
            Constraint.Constant(200)
            );
        Label halfWayDown = new Label
        {
            Text = "Halfway down and across",
            FontSize = 20,
            BackgroundColor= Color.Yellow,
            MaxLines = 2,
            LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.WordWrap,
        };
        relativeLayout.Children.Add(halfWayDown,
              Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
              {
                  return parent.Width / 2;
              }),
              Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
              {
                  return parent.Height / 2;
              }),

               // set the 1/3 width  of parent
               Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
               {
                 return parent.Width * 0.5;
               })
              );
        this.Content = relativeLayout;
    }
```

**Update:**

> But the first label ( upperLeft ) changes its line even when i did not
> pass the width value it automatically changes the line ?

The last label(`halfWayDown`) also could change its line, but the string hasn't reached the actual width.

As a test, you can use a long string to verify this,and the test code is:

```
Label halfWayDown = new Label
            {
                Text = "Halfway down and across 01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789",
                FontSize = 20,
                BackgroundColor = Color.Yellow,
                //LineBreakMode= LineBreakMode.CharacterWrap,
                //WidthRequest=200,
            };
            relativeLayout.Children.Add(halfWayDown,
                  Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
                  {
                      return parent.Width / 2;
                  }),
                  Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
                  {
                      return parent.Height / 2;
                  })

                   // set the 1/3 width  of parent
                   //Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
                   //{
                   //  return parent.Width * 0.5;
                   //})
                  );
```

The result is:

[image]

**Note:**

So to avoid this, you can set the width for your label(`halfWayDown` ).

**Update2:**

> you can see that the string of halfWayDown label have some missing
> characters. The part from "ss 012345" is missing.

That's because the two Lables `upperLeft` and `halfWayDown` both have  a default width.
You can verify this by adding a button,please refer the following code:

```
        Button button = new Button { 
         Text="test",
         HorizontalOptions= LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand

        };

        button.Clicked += delegate {
            double width1 = upperLeft.Width;
            double width2 = halfWayDown.Width;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("----> upperLeft's width = " + width1 + "<---> halfWayDown.Width = " + width2);
        };
        relativeLayout.Children.Add(button,
             Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
             {
                 return parent.Width / 3;
             }),
             Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
             {
                 return parent.Height*2 / 3;
             })

             );
```

And the output is as follows on my device:

```
----> upperLeft's width = 375.652173913043<---> halfWayDown.Width = 375.652173913043
```

So, to avoid this, you can set a width for your label(`halfWayDown`).

Comment: But the first label ( upperLeft ) changes its line even when i did not pass  the width value it automatically changes the line ?

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can check the updated part at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: There is a problem in your output also you can see that the string of halfWayDown label have some missing characters. The part from "ss 012345"  is missing.

Comment: Please check the updated part 2 in my answer.